# RegExp to delete comments

Tags: regex, groovy

the problem is - I need to delete all comments from a file (java code), so everything like `//this` or

```
/*  Multiline  */
```

comment should be deleted. I'm trying to achieve this by doing so

```
text = text.replaceAll($/(//.*\n)|(/\*[.\n]*\*/)/$, "")
```

but only one-line comments are removed from string. 
https://regex101.com/ shows that everything I need matches, can you please point to a problem?

Comment: if you do this line by line, how would you handle multiline comments (e.g. docblocks)?

Comment: I have one big string that represents whole text in a file

Comment: above code works more or less for me (the \n on the // comments is to greedy).  what is the actual problem?  please provide an error case

Comment: How about: `s = "/*"; a++; t = "*/";`? Simply replacing everything between `/*` and `*/` will leave you `s = "";`

Comment: @cfrick error case is that all block-comments are ignored and not replaced

Comment: Bart's right, this is always a bad idea

Comment: and it does for me.  so please provide a minimal example, that shows us your error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to turn on `DOTALL` mode to match `\n` with `.` in Java/Groovy regexs.  It can be turned on by embedding `(?s)` in the pattern.  Here's a working example:

```
def pattern = $/(//.*)|(?s)/\*.*\*//$
def singleLine = '''
    code // single line comment
    code
'''
def multiLine = '''
    code /* multi line
    comment */ code
'''
assert singleLine.replaceAll(pattern, '') == '\n    code \n    code\n'
assert multiLine.replaceAll(pattern, '') == '\n    code  code\n'
```

Comment: as Bart stated in the comments of the question, there are corner cases, that make using a regexp for job hard. `assert 'def url = "http://example.com"'.replaceAll($/(//.*)|(?s)/\*.*\*//$, '')=='def url = "http:'`

Answer (score 0):

You can use following regex

```
(\/\*.*(\n.*\n)*\*\/)|(\s*\/\/.*\n)
```

[Working demo on Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/hH8zS7/1)

Comment: Yeah, mine works there too. And this doesn't give any result - even single line comments are there.
http://s56.radikal.ru/i151/1503/a2/5bb681266d97.png